# wrapper for malloc and free that gives allocation statistics?

Tags: c, malloc

Is there a library I can use  (short of coding my own)  that provides me with statistics on how many times I've malloc'ed and free'ed, together with the number of allocated bytes?

Comment: closer care to comment?

Comment: I guess it is due to the "post asking to search for tools....". Righlty so, IMO.

Comment: @SJuan76: No, it's implied that I would like one that the community would vouch for, rather than finding my own.

Comment: Not so hard to roll your own...

Comment: Do you need a detection of memory leaks or just a "counter"?

Comment: @ollo. Just a counter. I need to know how much memory a concurrent data structure is actually consuming. Well, I do need to keep track of both malloc and free, but just the number of bytes allocated will work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want detect memory leaks etc., [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (see also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind)) is an option.

I know, this is a very, very basic method, but are `#defines` possible for your purpose?

*Eg. put something like this into a header:*

```
#ifdef COUNT_MALLOCS
static int mallocCounter;
static int mallocBytes;

// Attention! Not safe to single if-blocks without braces!
# define malloc(x)        malloc(x); mallocCounter++; mallocBytes += x
# define free(x)          free(x); mallocCounter++
# define printStat()      printf("Malloc count: %d\nBytes: %d\n", mallocCounter, mallocBytes)
#else
# define malloc(x)
# define free(x)
# define printStat()
#endif /* COUNT_MALLOCS */
```

Neither very flexible, nor safe, but it should work for simple counting.

**Edit:**

Maybe it's better to define `malloc()` to a custom function, so it's safe to single-line if-blocks.

```
static int mallocCounter;
static int mallocBytes;

// ...

static inline void* counting_malloc(size_t size)
{
    mallocCounter++;
    mallocBytes += size;
    return malloc(size);
}

static inline void couting_free(void* ptr)
{
    mallocCounter--;
    free(ptr);
}

#define malloc(x)      counting_malloc(x)
#define free(x)        counting_free(x)
```

Comment: thanks, yes, that should work. I will only have to lock the vars, since this is a multithreaded application.

Comment: Please see my edit; defining to a function is a better way, then the first one. You also can lock variables inside those.

Comment: How do you know the size to free in counting_free?

Comment: You are right, thank you for that hint. Evil copy-and-pase programming.